# What is the difference between d’après and après?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, prépositions

What is the difference between d’après and après, as in “le jour d’après demain”?

Comment: *Après*: after. *D'après*: according to. Now, if you happen to have a *de* before *après*, as in your question or @pirela's answer, you might mistake the two. Otherwise I don't think there's overlap. So the question is when you can say "le jour de" + après, avant, etc. rather than about d'après itself, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say 'après-demain' which is a day,
not 'le jour après-demain' which are two days,
but 'le jour d'après demain' is one day, the very one that belongs to après-demain.

Comment: Thanks! So would you say that “d’après” is the universal “after”? Would you say “moi d’après l’amour” or “leçon d’après le Français”? When do you use “après” then?

Comment: No. "D'après"   alone means 'relative to'. In "le jour d'après demain",  après is tied to demain.  When you say 'd' après moi... ' you say'  in my opinion'

Comment: Oh, I see! So, if I use, “après demain” without a hyphen, as in “after tomorrow”, can I say “le jour après demain”? I see why “le jour d’après-demain” is correct though.

Comment: Le jour après demain is a day  called après-demain !  Le jour d'après demain ( or après-demain) i 'll go back to my office :(

Comment: Demain=tomorrow, après demain=the day after tomorrow. le jour d'après demain is not  used.